# C++ constant reference in compare method on different platforms

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc

I have this piece of c++ code for sorting a struct,

```
const bool operator<(P& p) const {
  //...
}
```

It compiles without any problem on a linux device with "gcc 4.9.2".
But if try it on a windows machine with "gcc 4.7.1" (the one that comes with Code::Blocks 13.12), it gives nasty errors that you can see here http://pastebin.com/S28tD9kc

For compiling in both cases I've used: "g++ -std=c++11"

If I change "operator<(P& p)" to "operator<(const P& p)" it magically works. OK no problem I've made some mistake, but why does the first one not work on a windows machine if it works on a linux machine without any sign of problem?

An [example](http://pastebin.com/r5JpnwJX).

Comment: It should be `const bool operator<(P const & p) const {`

Comment: BTW you can and should use a later version of gcc with C::B .

Comment: @M.M no need for `const bool`, you've gone a bit too far.

Comment: @MarkRansom moot point really, it hurts readability but that's about it

Comment: I don't know why this is attracting downvotes, seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't DV, but questions like this should contain a MCVE. Without that , it's not possible to give an exact answer as to why the code appeared to work on one system. We can only speculate wildly.

Comment: @M.M I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I think the key is in this error message: `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const P' to 'P&'`. It implies that the implementation of `std::sort` has changed between the versions, and looking in both versions of `stl_algo.h` should provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because in those gcc versions sort is implemented differently. I have checked under VS2005 and it also produces such errors, but from looking into my stl implementation - I see lots of `const T&` parameters used when sorting. This will cause the same error you see if operator< is used with no const& parameter. I was able to compile such code using custom comparator and const_cast:

```
struct my_comp {
 bool operator() (const P& a, const P& b) const {
   return const_cast<P&>(a).operator<(const_cast<P&>(b));
 }
};
std::vector<P> pp(10);
std::sort(pp.begin(), pp.end(), my_comp());
```

I am not sure if this is correct code,just wrote it for compile experiment.

On the other hand, under Visual Studio 2015 it all compiles fine with non const parameter in operator<. In VS2015 sort uses move semantics, and this is what I suppose makes it compile.